# JMeter 5.0 - How to disable JSR223 caching by default

Tags: jmeter

I have a number of JMeter test plans that were created in JMeter 3.2.
In newer versions of JMeter, the "Cache compiled script if available" option is set to true by default on JSR223 components.

How can I set the caching option on JSR223 elements to false by default in JMeter 5.0?

Answer (score 0):

This is something which is present since [JMeter 3.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-3.3) - check [Bug #61640](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61640) and unfortunately this setting is not configurable by any means.

The options are in:

1. Change this line:

   ```
   <stringProp name="cacheKey">true</stringProp>
   ```

   to this one:

   ```
   <stringProp name="cacheKey">false</stringProp>
   ```

   in the .jmx script
2. Patch [ScriptingBeanInfoSupport](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/util/ScriptingBeanInfoSupport.java) source code and [recompile JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/building.html)
3. And the best of all: caching compiled scripts is very important for the scripts performance, they will run much faster and take less resources. If you experience any issues with your scripts with compilation caching set to `true` - they are badly designed (i.e. have inlined [functions and/or variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html))